# Matcher#matches() doesn't find pattern in String

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a code to get a specific set of url from a string of urls. If I test my regex on any tester, it's working fine but failing when I am testing it in Java code.

What am I doing wrong? Here is the regular expression and the rest of the code

**Java Code:**

```
public class RegexTry {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(http:\/\/(?:(?!http:\/\/).)*.AB.(?:(?!http:\/\/).)*(?=$|http))");
        String mydata = "http:\/\/this/is/anexample.jpg,http:\/\/this\/is\/anexample.jpg,http:\/\/this/is/anexample.jpg,http:\/\/this/is/anexample.jpg,http:\/\/this/is/anexamplewith.AB.jpg";
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
        if(matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Working");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

Not Working

Comment: working regex on tester: https://regex101.com/r/nT5fA2/1

Comment: What do you think `Matcher#matches` does and why do you think so?

Comment: Also, why are you escaping `/` ?

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis, you are right, I don't need to add escaping character. Actually, I am going to add this regex as a string in my database table to access it on the corresponding api call.
Hence added the escaping character But they are not required for this specific application.
Matcher.matches attempts to match the entire region against the pattern. If the match succeeds the it will perform the print operation.

Comment: That's right. The entire region is your String and it doesn't not, in its entirety, match the pattern.